# Customize maxNumberOfFiles of jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, multifile-uploader

I want to allow user upload only 1 file on some pages and more than 1 file on other pages. 
There're place to change this number

```
var parentWidget = ($.blueimpFP || $.blueimp).fileupload;
$.widget('blueimpUI.fileupload', parentWidget, {
    options: {
        // By default, files added to the widget are uploaded as soon
        // as the user clicks on the start buttons. To enable automatic
        // uploads, set the following option to true:
        autoUpload: false,
        // The following option limits the number of files that are
        // allowed to be uploaded using this widget:
        maxNumberOfFiles: undefined,
```

But if I change it here, it will be applied for all the jQuery Upload File controls on website. How can I customize the option maxNumberOfFiles to achieve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just define the value in the options for each page?

Page 1

```
{ maxNumberOfFiles: 5}
```

Page 2

```
{ maxNumberOfFiles: 1}
```

Or wrap it in it's own function passing in the number of files you want as an arg?

EDIT: 
OK - you've changed the question slightly since I posted this but the same thing applies